# deleting chart name,axis,legend,grid line for multiple graphs

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a loop of  graphs for every row to reflect the data beside it.
However, I've tried putting vba code to delete everything else in the chart to leave only the bar chart. it kept on saying error run time error. May I know what's the issue with my code? I've tried recording macro too, but it didn't work.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim strChrt As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim work As Integer


    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    work = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lastRow
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(x, "c"), ws.Cells(x, "D")).Select
        ws.Shapes.AddChart2("", xlBarStacked, Width:=500, Height:=50).Select

        strChrt = Trim(Replace(ActiveChart.Name, ActiveSheet.Name, ""))
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(strChrt).Left = ws.Cells(x, "G").Left
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart title").Chart
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(strChrt).Top = ws.Cells(x, "G").Top
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(strChrt).Chart = cht.Axes(xlCategory).Delete
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(strChrt).Chart = cht.Axes(xlValue).Delete
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(strChrt).Chart = cht.Legend.Delete
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(strChrt).Chart = cht.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(strChrt).Chart = cht.Axes(xlValue).MinorGridlines.Delete
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(strChrt).Chart = cht.ChartTitle.Delete
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(strChrt).Chart = cht.ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlNone
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(strChrt).Chart = cht.ChartArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(strChrt).Chart = cht.PlotArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse






    Next x
    End Sub
```

Comment: I think all the `ActiveSheet.Shapes(strChrt).Chart = ` should be removed, but untested.

Comment: i've tried removing it too but it didn't work

Comment: What line throws the run-time error?

Comment: run time error 5

Comment: What line in your *code* throws the error?

Comment: Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart title").Chart this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim work As Integer
    Dim chtObj As Shape

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    work = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lastRow

        ws.Range(ws.Cells(x, "c"), ws.Cells(x, "D")).Select

        Set chtObj = ws.Shapes.AddChart2("", xlBarStacked, _
                                        Width:=500, Height:=50) '<< the ChartObject
        chtObj.Left = ws.Cells(x, "G").Left
        chtObj.Top = ws.Cells(x, "G").Top

        With chtObj.Chart '<< the contained chart
            .Axes(xlCategory).Delete
            .Axes(xlValue).Delete
            .HasLegend = False '<<<
            .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete
            .Axes(xlValue).MinorGridlines.Delete
            .ChartTitle.Delete
            .ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlNone
            .ChartArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            .PlotArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        End With
    Next x
End Sub
```